# Fading an Image from Top to Bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade an image in from the top of it to the bottom of it, is there any way to achieve this ? I've looked for plugins but haven't had any luck thus far

Comment: what u have tried so far.. ?

Comment: Do you mean to fade the image on hover from the top to the bottom OR do you mean that the image is faded onto the background?

Comment: This is more of a CSS question. Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your question as you want to gradually fade in from top. If so this could be a start:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/7GKGM/)

Basically using an absolute div above the image and gradually setting gradient.

```
this.setFade = function() {
    this.fad.style.background = 
    "linear-gradient(to bottom, " + 
    "rgba(255,255,255,"+(this.pts/100)+") 0%," + 
    "rgba(255,255,255,"+(this.pts/this.aggr)+") 100%)";
}
```

You also might get away with something like this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kimiliini/7wxD2/)

Mainly using CSS transition for opacity on an element with gradient background. Would need some tweaking.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to find something like this but couldn't find it on the web.

Comment: @Crossman: Note that this is not cross-browser solution. Only meant as a starter. If you look at the fiddle of *acid* you'll see what you might have to add.

Answer (score 2):

You allways can put a div over the image and fade its background

```
    .overlay {
        content: '';
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);

    }
```

I've done this in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mYDLu/)